# How to run and debug an AngularJS application in Eclipse?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, angularjs, nodeclipse

I'm trying to get started with Nodeclipse. I would like to **run and debug** an AngularJS application, e.g. the `angular-phonecat` example from Eclipse.

In particular, I would like to

- use a *Debug on Server* launcher to start a server with my application and open a web browser (Firefox or Chromium).
- set a breakpoint in a JavaScript file in Eclipse
- click around in the web browser and have the Eclipse debugger stop at the breakpoint.

(The equivalent of this does work in NetBeans in a very intuitive way.)

From the Nodeclipse help, I don't see how to get started or whether this is possible at all.

I managed to run an debug a Node.js project with the Hello World template, but I don't see how to debug anything running in a web browser.

Does that require a Remote Javascript debug launcher? If so, how to use it?

Finally, I don't see how to actually **run** an AngularJS application in Nodeclipse. As far as I can tell, the AngularJS Eclipse plugin only implements editing features but does not deal with running and debugging. Do I need to turn the Angular project into a Node.js application? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS runs in browser, Node.js on server,
so you need different approaches.

Nodeclipse is primarily about supporting Node.js and has [ChromeDevTools-based debugger](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/tree/master/chromedevtools). I cannot tell what is best for debugging browser JavaScript, maybe it is Chrome browser.

> managed to run an debug a Node.js project with the Hello World template, but I don't see how to debug anything running in a web browser.

Ask on https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/

> Do I need to turn the Angular project into a Node.js application?

For Node.js run/debug it is not needed.